# I have to find the file with maximum speed size in azure data factory

Tags: azure, function, azure-pipelines, bigdata, azure-data-factory

I created an array variable and tried to pass that to max math function in ADF but i'm getting error in it. So how to using max function there?

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would be useful please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Array is one of the datatypes supported in ADF with both parameters and variables, so if you have a valid array then `max` will work either.  A simple example:

1. create a valid parameter of the Array datatype:
   [image]
2. Create a variable and add a Set Variable activity.  Use this expression as the `Value` argument:

   ```
   @string(max(pipeline().parameters.pInputArray))
   ```

NB I'm using the `max` function directly on the array and then `string` as only the String, Array and Boolean datatypes are supported for variables (at this time).